# Convert big number (hex value) to a string or number

Tags: javascript, node.js, remix, ethers.js, hardhat

**I got this result from calling to a method in a ERC20 token I have deployed on a testnet.**

```
contract MyToken is ERC20, ReentrancyGuard {}
```

**calling method,**

```
 let value = await ptrToken.balanceOf(wallet.address)
```

**I want to convert the resultant big number to a string or number.**

```
BigNumber { _hex: '0x021e19e0c9bab2400000', _isBigNumber: true }
```

I have tried the following three ways but, resulted 'undefined' as the output in nodejs.

```
1) const toEther = (_n) => {
    ethers.utils.formatUnits(_n, 'ether')
}

2) toTokens = (_n) => {
    ethers.utils.formatEther(_n)
}
3) const toEther = (_n) => {
    ethers.utils.formatUnits(_n.toString(), 'ether')
}
```

Passing the value to _n in both above functions resulted 'undefined'

Comment: The functions don't return anything?

Comment: functions return:  BigNumber { _hex: '0x021e19e0c9bab2400000', _isBigNumber: true } as the result.

Comment: I want to convert the resulting BigNumber (hex value) to a string or  a number.

Comment: Ok I got it. now. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: They return `undefined` because you are missing a `return` statement (or you have superfluous `{ }`).

Comment: They do not return any thing as the first commenter points out. My silly mistake :-).

Comment: So is there still a question, or will you delete the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my arrow function returning \`undefined\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73720021/why-is-my-arrow-function-returning-undefined)

Comment: You should see a question whether the question I just linked solved your problem. If you click "yes", this question will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
const theUsedAccount = await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", [0]);
const balance =  await provider.getBalance(theUsedAccount[0])
console.log("account used",theUsedAccount)
console.log("balance",ethers.utils.formatEther(parseInt(balance._hex).toString()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) ?

```
let bigVal = BigInt(value._hex);

//bigVal + 1n;
//bigVal > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
```

You can do all the normal comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

On ethers js v6: ❤

```js
    const provider = await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
    const address = await signer.getAddress();
    const balance = await provider.getBalance(address);
    console.log("balance: ", ethers.formatEther(balance))
```

Answer (score 0):

By using ethers library you can handle these easily.

For hexadecimal values you can use ethers.utils.formatEther(_hex)

so if the value is 0x3635c9adc5dea00000 ( equals to 1000 * 18**10 ) you can parse it to ether by directly passing it to formatEther