# Why is my arrow function returning `undefined`?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

*This question is intended as canonical duplicate target for questions about problems that stem from confusing the single-line/expression arrow function body syntax with automatic return with their multi-line/block version.*

---

I have an arrow function to add two numbers, but when I call it, it returns `undefined`. Why?

```js
const add = (a, b) => {
  a + b
}

console.log(add(1, 2)) // expected: 3, actually: undefined
```

---

**Alternative question:**

My React component is supposed to render list items using `map`, but the list stays empty. Why?

```
<ul>
  {list.map(item => {
    <li>
      <a href="{item.url}">{item.name}</a>
    </li>
  })}
</ul>
```

Comment: I swear, I searched for over 10 minutes and couldn't find that [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrow functions support two different styles of bodies: **expressions** and **blocks**.

If a single expression is provided (e.g. `a + b`) without braces `{ }` around it, that expression is automatically returned:

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b
```

If a block enclosed by `{ }` is provided, it works like a regular function body and requires a dedicated `return` statement to return a value:

```js
const add = (a, b) => {
  return a + b
}
```

Single-expression bodies are often used to write simple functions in a concise way which execute one operation or condition, as in the following examples:

```js
if (users.every(user => user.age >= 18)) { /* ... */ }

const emails = users.map(user => user.email)

const titleCased = string.replace(/\b\w/g, s => s.toUpperCase())

// in the following example, the return value is irrelevant
setTimeout(() => doStuff(1, 2, 3), 1000)
```

In most other cases, especially if you want to have multiple statements, loops or conditions in your function body, a block is used.

Note that you *can* have a function body spanning multiple lines even without a block if it is still a single expression, but if you would like to turn it into a block for readability reasons, you must not forget to add `return` (unless your function isn't supposed to return anything).

Now, this is the reason why your `add` function is returning `undefined` - it neither has a single-expression body (the `{ }` make it a block) nor does it have any `return` statement in its body. So, what happens is that `a + b` is evaluated, but the result isn't used for anything - it is thrown away and execution continues, reaching the end of the function and returning without any return value since none was given, i.e. returning `undefined`.

---

In the React case, the problem is the same. You are embedding the return value of a `.map` call, which should be an array of further content to render, but because your callback is not returning any value, you are mapping the items to several `undefined` values and rendering *that* at the end.

There is another twist here though: you may often need multiple lines in the element(s) that you return from a function like a `map` callback, but you will find that neither of the following two options looks quite clean:

```
<ul>
  {list.map(item => <li>
    <a href="{item.url}">{item.name}</a>
  </li>)}
</ul>

<ul>
  {list.map(item => {
    return <li>
      <a href="{item.url}">{item.name}</a>
    </li>
  })}
</ul>
```

Instead, what is usually done is **enclosing the expression in parentheses `( )`**. It is a still a single expression at the end, avoiding the need for an extra `return` statement, but is a lot nicer to work with:

```
<ul>
  {list.map(item => (
    <li>
      <a href="{item.url}">{item.name}</a>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

---

For more information about arrow functions in general, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas). To read about other differences between arrow functions and regular functions (such as different behavior of `this`), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable).

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions return code in **these cases**:

**Case 1**: When it's written inline like below

```js
/* notice that this is an implicit return 
and we don't need a return statement here as the code is 
in the same line after the => */

const add = (a, b) => a + b  
    
console.log(add(1, 2)) // expected: 3
```

**Case 2**: When it's written with `round brackets ()` like this

*Case 2 - example 1*

```js
/* notice the round bracket here. 
You will use this when you have a 
block of code here unlike case 1 
where you had a single line to return */

const add = (a, b) => ( // this is round bracket, no return needed 
    a + b 
    // and other blocks of code. Look at the below JSX example for
    // for this case
)

console.log(add(1, 2)) // expected: 3
```

The above example is similar to first case 2 - example 1, but this case is more suitable for a single block of code mostly for JSX like below

*Case 2 - example 2*

```js
<ul>
  {list.map(item => ( // this is round bracket, no return needed
    <li>
      <a href="{item.url}">{item.name}</a>
    </li>
  )}
</ul>
```

**Case 3**: With an explicit `return` statement when you use curly braces like this

```js
const add3 = (a, b) => { // curly braces + return statement
  return a + b;
};

const res3 = add3(1, 2);

console.log(res3); // 3
```

In your case, notice you're mixing both cases 2 and 3. Meaning, you are using curly braces as defined in case 3 and also not using return keyword then like in case 2 which is the reason it doesn't work.

Code : https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-ckjg69?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Your explanation of case 2 is a bit confusing because you can _not_ put a regular "block of code" inside of that consisting of any statements or more than one expression, it has to be still a single expression. It is in fact the same as case 1, the expression just being `( a + b )` now. (You could use the comma operator but then things quickly get ugly imo.) I also suggest splitting your code comments into multiple lines, they are currently a bit hard to read as they cause horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: Updated my answer! Let me know if you need more clarity.