# Filter array in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular project and I would like to filter an array of firms to find firm where domain is equal to this.domain. Here is my code for now. I was thinking something like: `let firms: Array<any> = this.firms.filter( (this.firms) => { if (firms.domain===this.domain) } )`

```
 import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {FirmProvider} from '../../providers/business/firm/firm.provider';
    import {Firm} from "../../providers/business/firm/firm";

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class FirmService {
      protected domain: string;
      protected firms: Firm[] = [];
      protected initialized: boolean = false;
    
      constructor(private firmProvider: FirmProvider) {
        this.domain = window.location.hostname.replace(/.\w+.\w+$/ig, '');
    
        if (this.initialized) {
          this.firmProvider
            .getAll()
            .then((firms) => {
              this.firms = firms;
              this.initialized = true;
              return firms;
            });
        }
      }
    
      all = (): PromiseLike<Firm[]> => {
        if (this.initialized) {
          return new Promise<Firm[]>((resolve) => {resolve(this.firms)});
        }
    
        return this.firmProvider
          .getAll()
          .then((firms) => {
            this.firms = firms;
            this.initialized = true;
            return firms;
          });
      }
    
      current() {
       
        // filter array of firms to find firm where domain is equal to this.domain
      }
    }
```

Comment: @SyedRafay the callback doesn't return a boolean. See: [Why is my arrow function returning `undefined`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73720021) and [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28889450)

Comment: Try `let firms: Array = this.firms.filter(firm => firm.domain === this.domain);`. Thanks @VLAZ.

Comment: let firms: Firm[] = this.firms.filter((firm: Firm) => firm.domain === this.domain);